# How to attach an image to a node while creating it with node_save($node);

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7

Hi i am working with drupal 7 and trying to import data from xml by parsing it using php and later on creating nodes with `node_save($node)`.

So far i have been succeeded to create nodes from xml without any images. I want to attach image to the node while i am importing it.

I know drupal 7 is still in alpha 6 but its good. `node_save($node)` function is almost same as in drupal 6 but little bit different.

Ok here is my code image file path is stored in a variable...any help would be great..thanks in advance

```
function main($head, $txt) {
  $nodes = array();
  $nodes[0]['title'] = $head; // node name
  $nodes[0]['body'] = $txt; // body text for the node
  $nodes[0]['teaser'] = '<p>A node</p>';
  $nodes[0]['timestamp'] = 1281765101;
  $nodes[0]['format'] = 2;
  make_nodes($nodes);
}

function make_nodes($nodes) {
  $new_node = $nodes[0];
  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = 'article';
  $node->status = 1;
  $node->uid = 1;
  $node->title = $new_node['title'];
  $node->promote = 1;
  $node->created = $new_node['timestamp'];
  $node->timestamp = $new_node['timestamp'];
  $node->changed= $new_node['timestamp'];
  $node->sticky = 0;
  $node->language = 'en';
  $node->body['und'][0]['format'] = 3;
  $node->body['und'][0]['summary'] = $new_node['teaser'];
  $node->body['und'][0]['value'] = $new_node['body'];
  $node->revision = 0;
  node_submit($node);
  node_save($node);
}
```

Comment: When you're programmatically creating nodes, be sure to populate $node->name, since `node_submit()` will change your `$node->uid` to 0 (anonymous) for all users who have permission to administer nodes, including your admin user.

Comment: thanks for the tip...but how i can attach picture with this node as a image

Comment: in drupal 7 this is not like that you dont have to populate $node->name.

Answer (score 2):

HI. After reading the documentation for 10 hours i finaly did it...i am including my code here

```
$uri = 'bird/bird_image.jpg';
$files =  new stdClass();
$files->uid = (isset($local_user->uid) && !empty($local_user->uid)?$local_user->uid:1);
$files->filename = 'bird.jpg';
$files->uri = $uri; 
$files->filemime = file_get_mimetype($uri);
$files->status = 1;
$files->timestamp = $new_node['timestamp'];

file_copy($files);
```

thats how one can upload file and to the drupal 7 database

Answer (score 0):

The original question Zero Cool asked was "How to attach an image to a node while creating it".

I haven't seen that fully answered anywhere, so here is some code that works for me in Drupal 7.27, on Windows 8 :)

The 'classified' content type for this node has 3 fields: title, body and field_advert_image (which is just an Image field type).

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'classified';

node_object_prepare($node); // Set some default values.

$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; 
$node->title = "Test node with image";

$node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = strip_tags("<b>Body text example</b>");
$node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['format'] = 'plain_text';     // or 'full_html' if you want

// Get pathauto to generate an URL alias
$node->path['pathauto'] = 1;
// Created by user 1
$node->uid = 1;

// The image directory has to be visible to Drupal on its local file-system,
// e.g. here it would be sites/default/files/adverts
$directory_uri = 'public://adverts';

// example image file in that directory:
$my_image_file = '32449.jpg';

// First create a file object, and add it to Drupal's managed_files table...
$file =  new stdClass();
$file->filename = $my_image_file;
$file->uri = $directory_uri.'/'.$my_image_file;
$file->filemime = file_get_mimetype($file->uri);
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
$file->uid = 1;
$file = file_save($file);
// ...then use the new file object.
$node->field_advert_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = (array)$file;

node_save($node);       

// N.B. node_save() gets the count incremented in the file_managed table; no need to call file_usage_add()

if ($node->nid) {
    echo "- Created node ".$node->nid." ... ".print_r($node,true)."\n";
} else {
    echo "- Drupal node_save API call failed\n";
}
```

As you probably guessed, this code runs from a command-line PHP script.

Hope it helps someone.