# How to attach image and tag with the node

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am working on a project to import XML contents into Drupal 7. I have parsed all the data in PHP.

So far i have succeeded in importing the node body and its title. There is no documentation for Drupal 7 on how to attach an image to the node and tags. I really need help, as I have spent two days trying to find a solution. I will be very grateful if anyone comes up with a solution. Please just guide me somewhere.

```
function make_nodes($nodes) {
  $new_node = $nodes[0];
  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->title = $new_node['title'];
  $node->body['und'][0]['value'] = $new_node['body'];
  $node->type = 'article';
  $node->created = $new_node['timestamp'];
  $node->changed = $new_node['timestamp'];
  $node->status = 1;
  $node->promote = 1;
  $node->sticky = 0;
  $node->body['und'][0]['format'] = 1;
  $node->uid = (isset($local_user->uid) && !empty($local_user->uid)?$local_user->uid:1);
  $node->language = 'en';
  $node->timestamp = $new_node['timestamp'];
  $node->revision = 0;
  node_submit($node);
  node_save($node);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to attach an image to a node while creating it with node_save($node);](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569498/how-to-attach-an-image-to-a-node-while-creating-it-with-node-savenode)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an [ImageField](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield) to your content type. This was a seperate module in Drupal 6 but moved into core in Drupal 7. There are some import scripts linked on the module page, but the API probably changed in Drupal 7.

You can also check out the [Migrate module](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) that provides a framework for importing into Drupal.

Comment: Hi. There is already ImageField in Article conetent type in drupal 7. thats where i want to save my images linked to the nodes.

Comment: There should be a function for that in the Field API (http://api.drupal.org/api/group/field/7), but that is an area that changed considerably in Drupal 7, the Drupal 6 way will not work anymore.

Comment: thats true i already tried drupa 6 way...it does not work....i am goign to try something

see the body of node is a field as well so i am accessing it like

node->body['und'][0]['value'] = $new_node['body'];

thats how to access fields in drupal 7 so it got me thinking that i can also access image field and tags field like maybe similar way

node->field_tags['und'][0]['value'] = 'something';

i am not sure but its soemething

Answer (score 0):

HI. After reading the documentation for 10 hours i finaly did it...i am including my code here

```
$uri = 'bird/bird_image.jpg';
$files =  new stdClass();
$files->uid = (isset($local_user->uid) && !empty($local_user->uid)?$local_user->uid:1);
$files->filename = 'bird.jpg';
$files->uri = $uri; 
$files->filemime = file_get_mimetype($uri);
$files->status = 1;
$files->timestamp = $new_node['timestamp'];

file_copy($files);
```

thats how one can upload file and to the drupal 7 database